# Naming different files. Handler? IO? Stream? Processor? Controller?

Tags: ruby

I'm having some trouble naming some files that I wrote. I don't really know the different between a stream, I/O, a handler, a processor (Is this a real concept?), and a controller. These are what my files look like in Ruby:

Starting from the rakefile:

```
desc "Calculate chocolate totals from a CSV of orders"
task :redeem_orders, [:orders_csv_path, :redemptions_csv_path] do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(:orders_csv_path => "./public/input/orders.csv", :redemptions_csv_path => "./public/output/redemptions.csv")

  DataController.transfer(
    input_path: args[:orders_csv_path],
    output_path: args[:redemptions_csv_path],
    formatter: ChocolateTotalsFormatter,
    converter: ChocolateTotalsConverter
  )
end
```

Then the controller (which in my mind delegates between different classes with the data obtained from the `rakefile`):

```
class DataController
  def self.transfer(input_path:, output_path:, formatter:, converter:)
    data_processor = DataProcessor.new(
      input_path: input_path,
      output_path: output_path,
      formatter: formatter
    )
    export_data = converter.convert(data_processor.import)
    data_processor.export(export_data)
  end
end
```

The processor (which performs imports and exports according to the various files that were passed into this file):

```
class DataProcessor
  attr_reader :input_path,
    :output_path,
    :formatter,
    :input_file_processor,
    :output_file_processor

  def initialize(input_path:, output_path:, formatter:)
    @input_path = input_path
    @output_path = output_path
    @formatter = formatter
    @input_file_processor = FileProcessorFactory.create(File.extname(input_path))
    @output_file_processor = FileProcessorFactory.create(File.extname(output_path))
  end

  def import
    formatter.format_input(input_file_processor.read(input_path: input_path))
  end

  def export(export_data)
    output_file_processor.write(
      output_path: output_path,
      data: formatter.format_output(export_data)
    )
  end
end
```

the `converter` referenced in the controller looks like this (it converts data that was passed in to a different format... I'm more confident about this naming):

```
class ChocolateTotalsConverter
  def self.convert(data)
    data.map do |row|
      ChocolateTotalsCalculator.new(row).calculate
    end
  end
end
```

And the `FileProcessorFactory` in the above code snippet creates a file like this one that actually does the reading and the writing to CSV:

require 'csv'

```
class CSVProcessor
  include FileTypeProcessor

  def self.read(input_path:, with_headers: true, return_headers: false)
    CSV.read(input_path, headers: with_headers, return_headers: return_headers, converters: :numeric)
  end

  def self.write(output_path:, data:, write_headers: false)
    CSV.open(output_path, "w", write_headers: write_headers) do |csv|
      data.each do |row|
        csv << row
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm having trouble with naming. Does it looks like I named things correctly? What should be named something like `DataIO` vs `DataProcessor`? What should a file named `DataStream` be doing? What about something that's a `converter`?

Comment: Seems more like an opinion-based code review question. Personally I find fluff like `FileProcessorFactory` and `ChocolateTotalsCalculator` to be anti-patterns in Ruby. With stuff like duck typing and blocks you can achieve similar levels of flexibility in a much more succinct and expressive way.

Comment: Great advice. Thank you man. Mind making this a full fleshed answer for me? For something like ChocolateTotalsCalculator... which is the heart of the program... how would you rename this? Eventually, wouldn't you want a full concrete class with specifics to do the actual work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby isn't a [kingdom of nouns](https://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html). Some programmers hear "everything is an object" and think "I am processing data, therefore I need a `DataProcessor` object!" But in Ruby, "every**thing** is an object". There's only one novel "thing" in your example: a chocolate order (maybe redemptions, too). So you only need one custom class: `ChocolateOrder`. The other "things" we already have objects for: `CSV` represents the CSV file, `Array` (or `Set` or `Hash`) can represent the collection of chocolate orders.

*Processing* a CSV row into an order, *converting* an order into workable data, and *totaling* those data into a result aren't "things". They're actions! In Ruby, actions are methods, blocks, procs, lambdas, or top-level functions*. In your case I see a method like `ChocolateOrder#payment` for getting just the price to add up, then maybe some blocks for the rest of the processing.

In pseudocode I imagine something like this:

```
# input
orders = CSV.foreach(input_file).map do |row|
  # get important stuff out of the row
  Order.new(x, y, z)
end

# processing
redemptions = orders.map { |order| order.get_redemption }

# output
CSV.open(output_file, "wb") do |csv|
  redemptions.each do |redemption|
    # convert redemption to an array of strings
    csv << redemption_ary
  end
end
```

If your rows are really simple, I would even consider just setting `headers:true` on the CSV so it returns `Hash` and leave orders as that.

* Procs, lambdas, and top-level functions are objects too. But that's beside the point.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like quite a 'java' way of thinking - in Ruby I haven't seen patterns like this used very often. I'd say that you might only really need the DataProcessor class. CSVProcessor and ChocolateTotalsConverter have only class methods, which might be more idiomatic if they were instance methods of DataProcessor instead. I'd start there and see how you feel about it.